# Remove duplicates from input string by used sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/sh/sed -nf
printf "Enter a string:-\n"
read -r string
printf "Entered string is:-\n"
echo "$string"
echo -e "${string}" |sed -nr '$!N;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P;D'
```

I'm new to bash scripting and I am trying to remove duplicates from a string whose input is given by the user. The problem is that its not removing anything. Below is the output

```
roschlynn@Asus-X512FL:~/Desktop/Shell$ bash pipelinecmd.sh 
Printing the string:-

1\n2\n2\n3\n3\n3\n4\n4\n4\n4\n5

1
2
3
4
5
Enter a string:-
king\quenn\king\jck
Entered string is:-
king\quenn\king\jck
king\quenn\king\jck
roschlynn@Asus-X512FL:~/Desktop/Shell$ ^C
roschlynn@Asus-X512FL:~/Desktop/Shell$
```

The first string is working perfectly as that is already defined. But the issue arises when i try to take the input from the user and pass it to the sed function. 
I'm guessing it's not passing the variable but how do I solve that issue?

Comment: Are you really sure that you use `#!/bin/sh/sed -nf` shebang and that you run the same script you have posted?

Comment: Are you perhaps misunderstanding escape sequences? In your first example `1\n2\n2\n3\n3\n3\n4\n4\n4\n4\n5`, the escape sequences are `\n` (interpreted as newline) whereas in your other example `king\quenn\king\jck` you have sequences like  `\q` and `\k` which AFAIK are just regular characters `q` and `k`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes it's the same script

Comment: @steeldriver i tried with \n too but its not working at all

Comment: By removing duplicates, do you mean that you just want one to remain? If that's the case, then just use sort -u